# PostgreSQL, how can i restrict access to code in a function for a user?

Tags: postgresql, roles, privileges, rights

I found out how to deny all access to tables for user in a schema.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA test FROM user;
```

But what can i do to restrict access to all functions in a schema, so that user couldn't read the code?

I was trying this:

```
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION test.test_function(text) FROM user;
```

Yes, it has restricted the ability to change a function, but not to actually see it.

What have i missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REVOKE access to the system view [pg_proc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-proc.html) or at least the column **prosrc** that hase the source code for the function.

Comment: i'm using here: REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE pg_catalog.pg_proc FROM user; But it's not working... the user still can see the table.

Comment: Did you also REVOKE public access? Your user is also "public": REVOKE SELECT ON TABLE pg_proc FROM public;

Comment: can i revoke only a specific function ?